# Unexpected NOTE from `pod lib lint`

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am creating my own CocoaPods and this is my first time. When I ran `pod lib lint` to validate, my CocoaPods passed validation but I got these notes unexpectedly.

```
-> SwiftyPod (0.0.1)
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'SwiftyPod' from project 'Pods')
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'Pods-App' from project 'Pods')
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'App' from project 'App')

SwiftyPod passed validation.
```

I'm using Xcode 11.5 (11E608c) and CocoaPod 1.9.3.

I'm not sure how to fix it. Is there a way to get around it? If anyone know how to fix it, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this message is generated by `xcodebuild` and can be ignored.